# Error in script declaration; Error:Cannot read property '1' of null

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript

I updated plugin JCH Optimize.
When it's enabled I get issue:

> Error in script declaration; Error:Cannot read property '1' of null

[image]
I tried to exclude this script and css, but it doesn't work.
[Link into](https://easy-moving.ca/piano-movers-toronto)

```
function parseMediaURL(media){
    let regexp=/https:\/\/i\.ytimg\.com\/vi\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\/maxresdefault\.jpg/i;
    let url=media.src;
    let match=url.match(regexp);
    return match[1];
}
```

I found out it's because of the script.
I guess I'm doing it wrong.

```
<p>
    <div>
        <div class="video">
            <a class="video__link" href="http://youtu.be/IDSJ0iMLq_U">
                <picture>
                    <source srcset="https://i1.ytimg.com/vi_webp/IDSJ0iMLq_U/maxresdefault.webp" type="image/webp">
                    <img class="video__media" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IDSJ0iMLq_U/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="7 steps in moving a piano from Piano movers Toronto #1.">
                </picture>
            </a>
            <button class="video__button" aria-label="Start the video">
                <svg width="68" height="48" viewBox="0 0 68 48">
                    <path class="video__button-shape" d="M66.52,7.74c-0.78-2.93-2.49-5.41-5.42-6.19C55.79,.13,34,0,34,0S12.21,.13,6.9,1.55 C3.97,2.33,2.27,4.81,1.48,7.74C0.06,13.05,0,24,0,24s0.06,10.95,1.48,16.26c0.78,2.93,2.49,5.41,5.42,6.19 C12.21,47.87,34,48,34,48s21.79-0.13,27.1-1.55c2.93-0.78,4.64-3.26,5.42-6.19C67.94,34.95,68,24,68,24S67.94,13.05,66.52,7.74z"></path>
                    <path class="video__button-icon" d="M 45,24 27,14 27,34"></path>
                </svg>
            </button>
        </div>
        <script>
            function findVideos() {
                let videos = document.querySelectorAll('.video');

                for (let i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
                    setupVideo(videos[i]);
                }
            }

            function setupVideo(video) {
                let link = video.querySelector('.video__link');
                let media = video.querySelector('.video__media');
                let button = video.querySelector('.video__button');
                let id = parseMediaURL(media);

                video.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    let iframe = createIframe(id);

                    link.remove();
                    button.remove();
                    video.appendChild(iframe);
                });

                link.removeAttribute('href');
                video.classList.add('video--enabled');
            }

            function parseMediaURL(media) {
                let regexp = /https:\/\/i\.ytimg\.com\/vi\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\/maxresdefault\.jpg/i;
                let url = media.src;
                let match = url.match(regexp);

                return match[1];
            }

            function createIframe(id) {
                let iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

                iframe.setAttribute('allowfullscreen', '');
                iframe.setAttribute('allow', 'autoplay');
                iframe.setAttribute('src', generateURL(id));
                iframe.classList.add('video__media');

                return iframe;
            }

            function generateURL(id) {
                let query = '?rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1';

                return 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + id + query;
            }

            findVideos();
        </script>
    </div>
</p>
```

The script for video YouTube instead of Iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I found it similar ask.
I solved it. Helpful answer [nevermind I solved the problem](http://I%20solved%20it%20it%20is%20helpful%20answer%20nevermind%20I%20solved%20the%20problem)

Comment: Your link is broken.  Please actually type the actual resolving technique into your answer.  We don't mind linking to other resources in an answer, but an answer should be able to stand alone without the link.  Please [edit].